# Decoding base64 string which is encoded in android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, base64

I have a string which i need to decode from ios but which encrypted in Android using base64.

```
String encoded = (Base64.encodeToString(vals, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Same string I am trying to decode in Objective C i am getting nil
// stringToDeccode string encoded in android

```
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:stringToDeccode options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

// decodedString is nil

the same string i have used this website which is able to decode.
https://www.base64decode.org/

Let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: Did you try passing different options to the `initWithBase64EncodedString` method?

Comment: What is the string?

Comment: I suggest to use not a Base64.DEFAULT but "String encoded = (Base64.encodeToString(vals, Base64.NO_WRAP));". This works fine with Objective-C or Swift standard decoding.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a problem in your input text.
Here is an Android code:

```
 String encoded = (Base64.encodeToString("IOS Developer".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Text encoded from Android is `SU9TIERldmVsb3Blcg==`.

iOS code:

```
  NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:@"SU9TIERldmVsb3Blcg==" options:0];
  NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"%@",decodedString);
```

Comment: where is encoding text just write here to test

Comment: can u please add swift sollution?

Answer (score 0):

For me it´s working:

// byteArray: is your image

Android:

String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

iOS/Swift 4:

```
    if let data = Data(base64Encoded: encoded, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters){
        return UIImage(data: data)
```

}